# How pritnOdd thread is able to proceed in below program to print natural numbers by even and odd threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, conditional-variable

Below programs works fine. But My doubt is very beginning both threads (printEven and printOdd) is waiting for signal on conditional variable( statement pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);) then how printOdd is able to proceed further even though printEven is not able so singal at that time.

I will put it in a simple way how the number 1 is getting printed ?
Can anyone please help I am literally stuck with this for long time.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t       tid[2];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t  cond;

int count = 1; // Shared variable to keep track of the current number to be printed

void* printEven(void* arg) {
    while (count <= 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (count % 2 != 0) {
            printf("waiting for cv signal\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        printf("Even: %d\n", count++);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* printOdd(void* arg) {
    while (count <= 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (count % 2 != 1) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        printf("Odd: %d\n", count++);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, printOdd, NULL);
    sleep(10);
    printf("creating even thread\n ");
    pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, printEven, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 1 gets printed because you are using `pthread_cond_wait` in exactly the way it is meant to be used. When `printOdd` is first called, `count` equals 1, so `count%2` equals 1, so the function *does not* call pthread_cond_wait.

In general, the right way to use pthread_cond_wait is,

```c
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (theNecessaryConditionIsNotYetMet()) {
        pthread_mutex_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    doSomethingThatRequiresTheConditionToBeMet();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

And, the whole point of locking the mutex is that no thread should ever change whether or not the condition is met except while it has the mutex locked.